# Splitting columns from a list of strings in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to create an Excel document based on a text file. Here's an example of my text file:

example.txt

```
|<Number1>|
    |TREE= 800  |
    |BIRD = 500 |
    |FISH = 25  |
    |DOG = 10   |
    |CAT = 5    |
    |ANOTHERCAT = 800   |
    |THERESOMANYCATS = 3    |
    |HAMSTER = 5    |
|<Number2>|
    |TREE= 800  |
    |BIRD = 500 |
    |FISH = 25  |
    |DOG = 10   |
    |CAT = 5    |
    |ANOTHERCAT = 800   |
    |THERESOMANYCATS = 3    |
    |HAMSTER = 5    |
```

My goal is to create a .csv file with that data. Currently this is my code and it works, however for some reason I can't figure out the formatting so that `|<Number1|` and `|<Number2>|` are in their own column with their own data. Something like this:

[image: excel1]

Currently I'm using the following code:

```
import re

setNames = ['|<Number1>|', '|<Number2>|']

for names in setNames:
    # Strip all spaces and dump all data into an array
    lines = [mo for mo in re.findall('(?s)(?<=\|)([<\w].+?)\s+?\|', open('numbers.txt').read())]
    # Create an array to hold the transformation
    print lines
    combined = ['' for x in range(len(lines) / lines.count(names[1:]))]
    print names[1:]
    # Append by rows
    for idx in range(len(lines)):
      combined[idx % len(combined)] += lines[idx] + ','

    # Write array to file
    output = open('numbersConverted2.csv','wb')
    for comb in combined:
      output.write(comb + "\n")
```

However my current code just stacks everything onto one column.

How can I edit my code so that when I reach the next entry in my list it creates a new column?

Comment: You could add some code that looks at each line, and if the first x characters are "<number" then move right one column. (Sorry, I don't know python too well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the "for names in setNames" loop, change to use this after 'print lines', then you don't need to list your column headings:

```
columns = sum([x.find('<')>=0 for x in lines])
combined = ['' for x in range(len(lines) / columns)]
```

The problem you have is that you're opening the file up for reading each time you go through the "for names in setNames" loop.

Comment: When you say get rid of loop you're speaking of my `idx` loop correct? `for idx in range(len(lines)):`

Comment: get rid of any lines that reference names or setNames

Comment: once again thank you! it worked going to keep studying it try to understand why this works over the previous code

Answer (score 0):

Running this ***VBA*** macro:

```
Sub NotPython()
   Dim iCol As Long, iRow As Long, pipe As String
   Dim TextLine As String
   iCol = 0
   iRow = 1
   pipe = "|"

   Close #1
   Open "C:\TestFolder\input.txt" For Input As #1

   Do While Not EOF(1)
      Line Input #1, TextLine
      TextLine = Trim(Replace(TextLine, pipe, ""))
      If InStr(1, TextLine, "Number") > 0 Then
         iRow = 1
         iCol = iCol + 1
      End If
      Cells(iRow, iCol) = TextLine
      iRow = iRow + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: I need a way to do this automatically when creating the CVS file and not using a built in Macro in Excel manually.

Comment: @JeanP  Then ignore my response.